# xsl:if-expression not working

Tags: xslt, xpath, conditional-statements, xslt-2.0

I got the following structure:

```
<root>
    <elements>
        <element>
            <key>1</key>
            <key2>10</key2>
        </element>
        <element>
            <key>2</key>
            <key2>100</key2>
        </element>  
    </elements>
</root>
```

I want to create a block of

```
<newelement></newelement>
```

when for example the value of `key` is `2` and the value of `key2` is not `''`

For selection of the element this XPath works perfectly:

```
/root/elements/element/key[text() = '2']/../key2[text() != '']
```

but when I put that into an `xsl:if` the transformation won't create my desired `newelement`

```
<xsl:if test="/root/elements/element/key[text() = '2']/../key2 != ''">
    <newelement></newelement>
</xsl:if>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It should work. See: http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2BL

Comment: Although your XPath expression will work, it is clumsy. It can be rewritten `/root/elements/element[key='2' and key2='']/key`

Comment: @helderdarocha: Thx 4 that play area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<root>
<elements>
     <element>
        <key>2</key>
        <key2>100</key2>
    </element>  
    <element>
        <key>2</key>
        <key2></key2>
    </element> 
</elements>
</root>
```

XSLT code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="elements">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:variable name="valueKey2" select="key2"/>
    <xsl:variable name="nameKey2" select="key2/name()"/>
    <xsl:if test="key[text() = '2'] and $valueKey2 != ''">
        <newelement>
            <!--use key2 as attribute of <newelement>-->
            <xsl:attribute name="{$nameKey2}"><xsl:value-of select="$valueKey2"/></xsl:attribute>
            <!--use key2 inside <newelemnt>-->
            <xsl:value-of select="$valueKey2"/>
        </newelement>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What if I want to select the value of key2 inside newelement? Is there a way to simplify that instead of recycling the entiry XPath-expression?